# Matching for math equations using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to write a preg_match for math equations, but for some reason when I print_r it nothing is showing up. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$text = "22/7";
preg_match("~([0-9]+([+\-*x]|(?:plus|add|minus|subtract|divide|time|multiply)(?:es|s)?(?: by)?)(?: )?[0-9]+)(((([+\-*x]|plus|add|minus|subtract|divide|time|multiply)(?:es|s)?(?: by)?)(?: )?([0-9]+))+)?~", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: It says there is an *Unmatched parenthesis*.

Comment: There is no divide symbol in any of the groups like this: `[+\-*x]`. Try switching these to `[+*x\/-]` (you don't need to escape the hyphen if it is at the end of a character group)

Comment: @KyleFairns Whahahahaha...I can't believe I made this mistake. When I tried to fix it my eyes just skips over the \ symbol, I thought that was the / symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Original Problem**

The problem was that there was no divide symbol present in the character group:

```
[+\-*x]
```

And should be changed to:

```
[+*x/-]
```

**Enhancement**

Having a further look into your regex, I wanted to see whether I could simplify it a little bit, while also adding functionality. I came up with this:

```
^((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[*+/^eE-]| (?:to the power of|plus|add|minus|subtract|divided?|times|multipl(?:y|ied))(?: by)?)(?: )?)(?1)*(?2)$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9B9ji1/8)

I've added:

- floating point numbers, (`1.58-0.58`)
- optional minus numbers, (`2*-4`)
- to the power of, (`2^8`)
- the scientific notation (`9e100`)
- a recursive pattern (`2^8*10-9`)

I'm glad you're using PHP - using the PCRE regex engine, you can do some pretty cool stuff.

Breakdown:

- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - capture an optional minus, followed by a digit, followed by an optional dot and more digits (minus and floating point additions)
- `[*+/^eE-]` - any character in this group (scientific notation, to the power of addition)
- `(?:to the power of|plus|add|minus|subtract|divided?|times|multipl(?:y|ied))(?: by)?` - any group in this (added "to the power of")
- `(?1)*(?2)` - Recurse group 1's regex (the entire of the pattern before it) as many times as possible, then recurse group 2's regex (the digit section), to always end on a number  (recursive pattern)